# List of Enum in Json Java

Tags: java, json, list, enums, postman

I want to send a request to my controller via Postman and I actually don't know the structure of a list containing Enum class

I'll give an example of a Enum to make it easy to explain:

```
public enum ReservationState {
     WAITING("Waiting"),
     BUSY("Busy"),
     READY("Ready");

     private String status;

     public ReservationState(String status){
         this.status = status;
     }
}
```

So how does a `List<ReservationState> reservations` look in a json string?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you mean `ReservationStatus` or `ReservationState`?

Comment: The ReservationSTatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `{"reservations": ["WAITING", "BUSY", "READY" ]}`

Comment: It should be enum names, to use values there should be \@Jsonvalue / \@JsonCreator

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "reservations": [
        "WAITING",
        "BUSY",
        "READY"
    ]
}
```

unless you provided special serializer, enums are serialized as their enum literals